# Four buttons use One Function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing this in React.

Right now I have 2 sets of numbers which are controlled by 4 buttons; 2 increment buttons and 2 decrement buttons.  The increment buttons raise each number, the decrement buttons lower each number.

I've created a function that does this for one of the decrement buttons. But I don't know how to make it dynamic based on which button is clicked. I don't want 4 separate functions, I'd prefer 2 functions or even just 1.

This is the function:

```
decrementClick() {
        if (this.state.breakLength > 1) {
          this.setState({ breakLength: this.state.breakLength - 1 })
        }  
    }
```

And this is the JSX code:

```
<button id="break-decrement" onClick={this.decrementClick.bind(this.decrementClick)}>▼</button>
```

I can pass a value from the button into the function, but how can it modify the proper state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    foo: 0,
    bar: 0
  }

  handleUpdateCounter(counterId, operation, event) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      [counterId]: operation === 'increment' ? prevState[counterId] + 1 : prevState[counterId] - 1
    }));

  }

  render() {
    const { foo, bar } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
          Foo: {foo}, Bar: {bar}
          <button onClick={this.handleUpdateCounter.bind(this, 'foo', 'increment')}>I increment foo</button>

          <button onClick={this.handleUpdateCounter.bind(this, 'bar', 'decrement')}>I decrement bar</button>

      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

The trick is to use .bind() to create a new version of `handleUpdateCounter` with some of the arguments "fixed".

A couple of notes:

```
{
 [myVar]: "test"
}
```

is how you set a dynamic key in the object, using the key name stored in myVar as a string.

We use this.setState(callback) to make sure we read the previous value of the counter, since setState is asynchronous.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This totally answers my question. 

Is there a way to access the value of this.state.foo outside of the setState?  I want to use an if statement to check if the numbers are within a certain range.

Comment: @AdamWeiler No problem. Within any method of the component, you can always access the current state by doing ```this.state.foo```

Comment: What I mean to say, the handleUpdateCounter() is working with both foo and bar now.  Is there a way to dynamically write an if statement that would work for either foo or bar?   Example: if ([counterId] > 1) -- Or maybe: if (this.state.[counterId] > 1)

Comment: @AdamWeiler I think you may just need to use this.state[counterId]  (or prevState[counterId] in my example). Use myObj[myKeyVar] to dynamically access to a key in an object.

Comment: No problem, nice one.